# Can you configure the Visual Studio Find Options?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to get the VS 2012 find dialog to always use *Current Document* and reset *case* & *whole-word* when I press Ctrl+F? Currently it remembers my last options and I often forget to turn them off.

Also it sometimes switches to *All open documents* on its own which totally throws me off. I haven't yet figured out why or when this happens.

I've searched for registry keys and extensions but so far nothing useful has turned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've published a Visual Studio "SmartFind" extension to fix this issue.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/015611c4-b357-4672-8977-f3ec92f0b808

Comment: Not sure when I'll find the time. Want to take a look at the source? https://github.com/laktak/vs-smartfind

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to get the dialog or the quick find UI to always choose a specific scope out of the box. During beta of VS 2012, this behavior was implemented where CTRL+F would always set the scope to Current Document and Ctrl+Shift+F would set the scope Entire Solution upon invocation of the commands. A lot of users were unhappy with this behavior, so it was reverted. There are no registry keys that you can set to alter this behavior.

Visual Studio always tries to reuse the last used scope. There are circumstances at which that scope is  not available, and that'll cause the IDE to change the scope on you. Let's suppose you do a search in "Current Project", after that you close the entire solution and then invoke the dialog. The scope will have to change to something else.

You probably know about this, but Ctrl+F3 will search for the word that is under the caret and it'll always perform that search with the Whole Word option on in the current document. Perhaps that'll suit your needs.

Comment: At least in Visual Studio 2019 this does not appear to be true, Ctrl+F3 just updates the search expression - it does not change the scope or other options (e.g. Regex).